# PYTHON MOVER ARQUIVO PARA OUTRA PASTA USANDO DEF

Tags: python

Tenho vários arquivos em uma pasta e gostaria de mover para diferentes pastas, conforme o nome do arquivo, usando um método. Exemplo: ARQUIVO 1 para PASTA 1. ARQUIVO 2 para PASTA 2.
Quero colocar no método tanto o nome do arquivo quanto o caminho da pasta. Não quero colocar o caminho da pasta dentro do IF, mas no método.

```
import os
import shutil
import time
import requests
from zipfile import ZipFile

caminho = r"P:\12.ESCRITA FISCAL\NOTAS ENTRADAS"
lista_arquivos = os.listdir(caminho)


def MOVER(nomeempresa, caminhopasta):
    for arquivo in lista_arquivos: 

        if nomeempresa in arquivo: 
            os.rename(f"P:/12.ESCRITA FISCAL/NOTAS ENTRADAS/{arquivo}", caminhopasta/{arquivo})
   
MOVER("ARQUIVO 1"; f"P:/12.ESCRITA FISCAL/NOTAS ENTRADAS/PASTA 1/102022")
```

ERRO:

Input In [38]
MOVER("ARQUIVO 1"; f"P:/12.ESCRITA FISCAL/NOTAS ENTRADAS/1-MENBERT/102022")
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score -3):

Boa tarde,

tem uns erros de sintaxe, precisa mudar alguns campos:

```
#f"{caminhopasta}/{arquivo} - pois o símbolo de divisão irá ocasionar erro, pois não está tratando com números e sim com string
# para passar os parâmetros na função, separe por virgulas 
os.rename(f"P:/12.ESCRITA FISCAL/NOTAS ENTRADAS/{arquivo}", f"{caminhopasta}/{arquivo}")

MOVER("ARQUIVO 1", f"P:/12.ESCRITA FISCAL/NOTAS ENTRADAS/PASTA 1/102022")
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).